# How do I implement sending a _Recordset ** parameter to a COM+ application

Tags: c++, visual-c++, com, dcom

I have a COM+ VB6 application, I generated a header file using the MIDL compiler.
The header contains the following definition:

```
   virtual /* [id] */ HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE Gett( 
    /* [in] */ BSTR sPostCode,
    /* [in] */ BSTR sSurname,
    /* [retval][out] */ _Recordset **__MIDL_0012) = 0;
```

In my c++ client call that calls this ive imported

```
    #import "C:\Program files\Common Files\System\Ado\msado15.dll" 
rename("EOF", "ADOEOF")
```

The GetAddress function is then being called as follows:

```
void AddressLookup::GetAddress(_bstr_t postCode, _bstr_t address)
{
   ADODB::_RecordsetPtr recordset;
   HRESULT hr = recordset.CreateInstance(__uuidof(ADODB::Recordset));

   m_pIAddressLookup->Gett(postCode, address, recordset);
}
```

but i keep geting this compiler error:

> AddressLookup.cpp(20) : error C2664:
>   '_AddressLookup::Gett' : cannot
>   convert parameter 3 from
>   'ADODB::_RecordsetPtr' to '_Recordset
>   ** '
>           No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform
>   this conversion, or the operator
>   cannot be called

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
m_pIAddressLookup->Gett(postCode, address, recordset);
```

should be

```
m_pIAddressLookup->Gett(postCode, address, &recordset);
```

(note `&` in front of `recordset` - it means "take address of" - in case of the smart pointer you're obviously using this will call overloaded `operator&()` and this will give you the address of the interface pointer stored inside the smart pointer).

Comment: I get an exception: AddressLookup.cpp(20) : error C2664: '_AddressLookup::Gett' : cannot convert parameter 3 from '_com_ptr_t<_IIID>::Interface ** ' to '_Recordset ** '
        with
        [
            _IIID=_com_IIID<ADODB::_Recordset,& _GUID_00000556_0000_0010_8000_00aa006d2ea4>
        ]
        Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast'

Comment: @Alan: That's not an exception, that's a compilation error. The problem is something with namespaces. What's the namespace containing the definition of `_Recordset`?